# Static PreHeader isnt-appearing in inbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio

We've put a static preheader in an email in email Studio, when we were running tests we received the email without the preheader and the mirror link was there instead. the same happened with single sending.

We tried the following :

```
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
<div class="preheader" style="font-size: 0px; display: none !important;">Preheader </div>
```

It worked but we still can't understand why the static preheader written in the box isn't appearing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Marketing Cloud, you need to set the static preheader in the specified field in Content Builder. The preheader is automatically added to the email upon send, where it is being injected as the first content of the HTML email.

[image]

If you want to define it within the email, you need to set the preheader variable in the source code of the email, before your `<body>` tag, e.g.:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @testPreheader = "hello ben-man"
]%%
<body>
```

And referencing it in the email like this:

[image]